# How to size CollectionViewCell dynamically using iOS 8 methods

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to apply the self-sizing cells on iOS 8 for a collectionView. However, settings the estimatedItemSize property is not enough. I've also implemented the preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes but the cells seem to be off.

What am I missing?

In my ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        var flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        var width = collectionView.frame.width
        //where does this value come from? isn't this supposed to be dynamic now???
        flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(width, 100.0);
    }
```

Cell Class:

```
@IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var starsView: HCView!
    @IBOutlet var starsSubtitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var bodyLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var footerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var line: UIView!

    //I thought we didn't need to implement anything else???? Why are we basically calculating the size for everything
    //If using autoLayout???
    override func preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes(layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes! {

        var attr = layoutAttributes.copy() as UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
        var bodySize = bodyLabel.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(layoutAttributes.frame), CGFloat.max))
        var titleSize = titleLabel.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(layoutAttributes.frame), CGFloat.max))
        var starsSubtitleSize = starsSubtitle.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(layoutAttributes.frame), CGFloat.max))
        var footerLabelSize = footerLabel.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(layoutAttributes.frame), CGFloat.max))

        var newFrame = attr.frame
        newFrame.size.height = bodySize.height + titleSize.height + starsSubtitleSize.height + footerLabelSize.height
        attr.frame = newFrame
        return attr
    }
```

The cell ends up being too short, and truncates the bodyLabel...